# Looping until correct input

Tags: python

I am trying to create a loop until the correct input is inputted but if a wrong answer is inputted, the code loops around the "print ("Invalid input, check spelling error")" forever. What am I supposed to do so that the entire code repeats again re-asking for an input?

```
count = 0

while count == 0  :

    if ChosenProcessor == ("p3"):
        PCPrice = PCPrice + 100 
        count = count + 1
    elif ChosenProcessor == ("p5"):     
        PCPrice = PCPrice + 120
        count = count + 1
    elif ChosenProcessor == ("p7"):
        PCPrice = PCPrice + 200
        count = count + 1
    else:
        print ("Invalid input, check spelling error")
```

This is my first question ever so my apologies if its pretty pointless or already asked. If it is asked I would also appreciate a link or the title to that question.

Comment: You should start by properly indenting your code.

Comment: Where is the code that prompts the user for input?

Comment: @Meepwned It kind of matters, since where and how you're doing that is central to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:

    ChosenProcessor = input('Enter the answer: ')

    if ChosenProcessor == ("p3"):
        PCPrice = PCPrice + 100
        break

    elif ChosenProcessor == ("p5"):     
        PCPrice = PCPrice + 120
        break

    elif ChosenProcessor == ("p7"):
        PCPrice = PCPrice + 200
        break

    else:
        print ("Invalid input, check spelling error")
```

This code will keep asking for an input until `ChosenProcessor` is equal to one of your inputs. If `ChosenProcessor`is equal to one of your inputs the loop will stop. (`break` exits a while/for loop)

Comment: Ah I just realized the silly mistake I made now thanks to you, man, it sure is annoying to not see the mistakes you make even though its right in front of you and so obvious.